# How do I use Google's autocomplete in Javascript (Cross Domain)?

Tags: javascript

I want to use Google's auto complete via this url:

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=Google
```

But the problem is when I try to make an ajax call to it, the browser will refuse to send the request since its a cross domain request.

How can I make it possible to use it in Javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible to perform cross-domain ajax requests if the server (google) does not support [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [cors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). You could try a workaround:

- Expose this function on your server (`http://yourserver/pathtofunction`). The browser could call it passing in the parameters as query string (e.x `output=toolbar&hl=en&q=Google`)
- Your server then calls `http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search` with the passed query string parameters to get the returned result and return it to your browser.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this user guide can help:

```
http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=What_Would_Google_Suggest%3F
```